# No module named 'scikit_posthocs'

Tags: python, pandas, api, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to run a post-hoc test on an LM in pandas and I want to use the scikit_posthocs package as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sa
import statsmodels.formula.api as sfa
import scikit_posthocs as sp
sp.posthoc_ttest(newdf, val_col='duration', group_col='alcohol', p_adjust='holm')
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
No module named 'scikit_posthocs'
```

I am using an anaconda environment - I have tried to install scikit_posthocs on the anaconda terminal using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-posthocs
```

But this gives me the error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scikit-posthocs.
  - /users/macbook/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

I would be so grateful for any advice you may have!

Answer (score 1):

The issue has now been solved. I tried the following command again:

> conda install -c conda-forge scikit-posthocs

And it worked!

Have a great day :)